# Color profile inside JPEG file

Tags: color, color-management, jpeg, web, color-spaces

**1) What is the best practice for color profiles embedded in .JPG images, for web?** (non print)

- sRGB profile stored in .JPG file ?
- AdobeRGB profile stored in .JPG file ?
- no profile setting in .JPG file (how to remove an exisiting profile in Photoshop?) ?

I do know that there will be color differences from one screen to another (computer, laptop, phone, another phone, etc.) but **I'd like to avoid color differences due to a browser / phone photo display app not understanding correctly the profile.**

*Context: I've shot photos with a Panasonic GF1 (in RAW), then worked on them with Lightroom, then exported them to a .JPG file. And finally I did some minor modifications with Photoshop CS5.*

**2) How to know the current setting of a .JPG about its color profile?**

Here is what I have for a particular .JPG photo (I hope it's transparent and understandable) in the 3 dialog boxes about color / profiles of Edit menu of Photoshop CS5:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not all browsers support colour management, and if they don't, they'll act like the images are encoded in **sRGB**. Since sRGB is also the 
**default** for images without an embedded profile, this is the **safest option** for images intended to be viewed via web browser.

It doesn't make much of a difference whether you embed sRGB or no profile at all.

PS does have an option in the colour management settings to **warn you** if an images colour profile differs from the set working profile - this is a good idea to turn on, then you'll see the images' colour profile in the **warning dialog** on opening the image, together with the option to convert it, use the images profile as working profile or ignore the difference (not recommended).

You can set the information displayed at the bottom of each image window in PS to show you the colour space.

Comment: Thanks. What is "the set working profile" ? Can you add a screenshot of this dialog? PS if you can send an example JPG with a difference profile, I'll try to open it to see if this warning dialog comes. Last thing: is sRGB IEC61966-2.1 the standard one?

Comment: "the set working profile" : the working profile you have set in the color management options. the "espace de travail" in your 3rd screenshot. to get an example, just create one via the convert dialog you show in your question.